# 'No such file or directory' - MyApp.app in DerivedData

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode8

Note: This began directly after I installed the Pinterest SDK through Cocoapods but I was using several Cocoapods before the error occurred:

Whenever I build or run the project, I get an error sometimes when it's running '[CP] Embed Pod Frameworks' and sometimes when it's 'Copying MyApp.app'. The error is always along these lines

```
/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fjeanqlyrtcollgyssfnlulisdan/Build/Products/Debug-watchos/MyApp.app: No such file or directory
```

but sometimes its not 'Debug-watchos', sometimes its 'Debug-iphonesimulator' or 'Debug-iphoneos'. And I've gone to those folders in Finder - In my project, I have 4 targets: 'MyApp 0.5', 'MyApp 0.5UITests', 'MyApp', 'MyApp Extension'. So in Finder, sometimes if it says it can't find 'MyApp.app', 'MyApp 0.5.app' IS there, 'MyApp.app' is not.

I've cleaned the build folder, deleted DerivedData, and run 'pod deintegrate', 'pod clean', then 'pod install' multiple times. I also removed Pinterest from the Podfile so it was removed from the project.

Specifics: Swift 3, Xcode 8.1

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

'Debug-watchos', 'Debug-iphonesimulator' or 'Debug-iphoneos' is always thesame issue, but running on Watch, Simulator or real iPhone.

Check your schema, make sure you are actially building the `MyApp` target:

[image]